# Internet Connection Sharing(ICS) on windows 7 does not work even though connected to host

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, android, tethering

So below are the details of hardware/software I am using for ICS.

1.Windows 7 as host

2.Android Phone(Micromax canvas 2 as client

3.EDUP nano usb wifi adapter

4.Data card(usb modem) for internet access on Windows 7

So I have enabled the sharing and done all the basic stuffs required for ICS.
Below are the snapshots of some settings:
[image]

[image]

Now when I try to connect my android via wifi,I gets connected successfully. I am able to send files over wifi, Use DroidCam **BUT** Unable to access internet. When I try to use internet on phone,The browser tries to load the page for a while and finally times out. SO where I am making mistake? I also used Connectify but no luck! Please help!

Comment: I'm sure `cmd.exe` ->  `ipconfig /all` on the host PC + Android detailed network info (e.g by using "Network Info II" apps) would help us understand the situation better. Network topology map would also be a plus (though I can roughly understand your topology without one). You might want to mask your public IP and MAC address before posting the info.

Comment: Thank You But already tried all these!